# cat not recognised as an internal or external command

Tags: windows, openssl, cat

Learning about big query on google app engine and wanted to try out [this library](https://github.com/tylertreat/BigQuery-Python) that also required me to know about [Converting the service account credential to other formats](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication?hl=en#converting-the-private-key). I have tried the command

```
# Convert the key from pkcs12 to pkcs1 (PEM).
$ cat /path/to/xxxx-privatekey.p12 | openssl pkcs12 -nodes -nocerts -passin pass:notasecret | openssl rsa > /path/to/secret.pem
```

on the command line but I get

```
'cat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: `cat` is a *UNIX* command, not available on Windows. `openssl` is also not going to be available as a command.

Comment: None of this has anything to do with Python, by the way.

Comment: In the Windows command prompt you can replace `cat` with `type`, but that still won't fully solve your problem.  As @MartijnPieters points out, this command can't work unless you have openssl installed

Comment: i have openssl installed already. would try replacing cat with type.Thanks

Comment: I don't have a Windows environment to test this for you, but there are several results available when googling for "Convert the key from pkcs12 to pkcs1 windows", including a [Powershell option](http://www.sysadmins.lv/blog-en/how-to-convert-pkcs12pfx-to-pem-format.aspx).

Comment: Install [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) and it will be helpful. Cygwin adds some unix commands and tools to windows enviroment.

Comment: @MartijnPieters in PowerShell `cat` is an alias to `Get-Content` which is an equivalent to Unix `cat` depending on the input and arguments

Comment: @phuclv the OP is not using powershell though, and in 2015 powershell wasn’t nearly as widely available. Was the `cat` alias available in 2015?

Comment: @MartijnPieters that's not true. PowerShell was always available since Windows Vista in 2006 so it's extremely common for more than a decade. And it has always had most of the POSIX-like aliases. Only when PowerShell became cross-platform some of them were removed in some platforms like `curl` or `ls` to avoid confusion

Comment: @phuclv I don’t use Windows myself, and powershell wasn’t open sourced in 2016. I had the impression that wider adoption took a while at any rate.

Comment: @MartijnPieters but `cat` is always available since Vista regardless of adoption rate. Anyway it has been already very commonly used before being made cross-platform

Answer (score 35):

Use windows powershell.  WIndows 7 afterwards, it comes along with the windows.

Comment: Powershell solved the issue for me. Thanks

Comment: PowerShell is included since Windows Vista, **not** Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Use 'Windows PowerShell' to the 'cat' Command, It'll work.